# what is api_key in swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-restcontroller

I am new on Swagger , I am able to run swagger UI  with spring .

But I want to know what is api_key in swagger . What is use of api_key ?
Could be search any api (rest controller in spring ) with api_key ? than how to configure that api with api_key with spring rest controller ?

If Any App has more than 100 controller in swagger UI than it will be difficult to find out particular controller . Could we simplify the process of finding that particular controller in this scenario ? it is relates to api_key .

[image]

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

If your api use some kind of authentication like OAuth 2.0 or Basic Authentication you must provide a token to authenticate and authorize the access to call the API.

The api_key field in swagger ui is a way to provide this token that you can test your API. This token goes on Authentication HTTP Header.